# Getopts function issue

Tags: bash

Trying to make a bash script that moves files into a trash directory and has some other features. To implement these features I'm trying to use the getopts function but am struggling to even implement a help feature or user manual. When I run the script and try to use -h, the script doesn't recognize it's an option and just runs normally as if it were a file. How can I fix this?
FIXED:

```
#!/bin/bash
trash=~/TRASH
if [ ! -e $trash ]; then
  mkdir $trash
elif [ ! -d $trash ]; then
  echo "$0: error: $trash is not a directory"; exit 1
fi

while getopts "h" options; do
case $options in
h) echo "This is the help option."
exit;;
\?)
echo: "Invalid option"
exit;;
esac
done

while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
  if [ ! -e $1 ]; then
    echo "$0: error: tried to delete file that does not exist: $1"
    shift
    continue
  fi
  tarname="$1.tar"
  tar -cf "$tarname" "$1"
  mv "$tarname" $trash
  rm -rf "$1"
  shift
done


echo "Cleaning $trash directory"
now=`date +%s`
cd $trash
for f in `ls`; do
  fileage=$(stat -c '%Y' "$f")
  if [ $((now-fileage)) -gt $((60*60*24*2)) ]; then
    rm -rf "$f"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Your code has many issues. Try https://www.shellcheck.net/ to fix them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it was a simple fix, simply moved the getopts function to the top, to occur before anything else and it works now.

Comment: Yes, you have to process the options before looking at the remaining arguments. After the `while getopts` loop, don't forget to `shift $((OPTIND - 1))`

Comment: What does that do?

Comment: It will remove `-h` from the positional parameters, so the `while [ $# -gt 0 ]` loop will not see it. `getopts` processes the options, but it does not automatically shift them away. It uses the OPTIND variable to count how many arguments to remove.

Comment: I also created an option to do the basic use of the script but for directories, it's very similar, using that same while loop, however in the part where it detects if the directory exists or not, -r is always detected as a directory that doesn't exist. Is this the reason why? I also tried to put this in the -r option but it still happens

Comment: Am I supposed to understand the code that I can't see?

Comment: Fair enough, am posting another question since I got a lot of issues with these options